# Режет слух новое название окончания блокады Ленинграда....

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Президент РФ Владимир Путин подписал закон о корректировке названия памятного дня, посвященного снятию блокады Ленинграда, сообщается в субботу на сайте Кремля.
Документ изменяет наименование дня воинской славы России «27 января — День снятия блокады города Ленинграда (1944 год)» на «27 января — День полного освобождения Ленинграда от фашистской блокады (1944 год)».*

Блокаду все-таки снимают или от нее освобождают? Понимаю, что "снять" могут и те, кто ее организовал, и толковать можно двояко, но все же? "Освободить от блокады..." Ну неправильно как-то!

Comment: > **«Обстоятельная реляция» о Полтавской битве (1709)** Междо тем послал его царское величество его светлость генерала князя Меншикова да при нем генерала-лейтенанта Ренцеля с некоторою частию кавалерии и инфантерии к Полтаве, дабы еще в сукурс неприятелю идущия войска, також и в шанцах оставшагося неприятельского генерала-маеора Роза с неприятельскими войски атаковать и помянутый город **от блокады** веема **освободить**.

Comment: Выражение "День снятия блокады города Ленинграда (1944)" - пустое имя.

Answer (score 3):

Блокаду в норме **прорывают**, если это разовая или неокончательная акция. Или **ликвидируют**, если окончательная. Действие само называется деблокацией. 
Эти названия использовались и ранее. Но какое-то время назад (годах в шестидесятых) какую-то умную голову посетила идея, что тут недостаточно пафоса.

Впрочем, нашлось объяснение, что, дескать, собственно прорыв был неделей раньше (20 января - соединение в районе Красного Села войск Волховского фронта и 2 ударной армии с Ораниенбаумского плацдарма), а тут, типа, требуется точность. Оговорюсь, что я не про события января 1943 г.

Разумеется, "снятие" ни черту не годилось, ибо снять её могли только те, кто устанавливал: немцы и финны.
*Все это, кстати, в конечном счете привело к тому, что "Блокада (Ленинграда)" стала восприниматься сама по себе, как имя собственное, с собственно блокадой в нарицательном смысле имеющее не так уж много общего*.

Так что замена названия - дело в общем-то правильное. Но в данном случае это замена шила на мыло. "Освобождение от блокады" термин тоже неудачный.  По другим, правда, причинам. Во-первых, название праздника из десятка слов всегда вызывает нервный тик. Оно неизбежно будет стянуто до "дня Освобождения Ленинграда", что вряд ли соответствует истории и замыслу бюрократов. А во-вторых, потому, что день разгрома немецкой группировки надо считать днем освобождения от блокады. Может потому, что победа в той операции (в отличие от, скажем, Сталинграда) была не полной и не окончательной. 
Впрочем, это уже к военным историкам. Ну и должен признать, что возражения Марка Иза по поводу "окончательного"-"неокончательного" тоже не лишены смысла. Причем как в отношении снятия, так и освобождения. ))) Перемудрили в обоих случая.

Comment: Спасибо за спокойно высказанное мнение!

Comment: Я, как человек не совсем чуждый военный истории (мне, правда, ближе войны более ранние), должен сказать, что сама операция "Январский гром" для меня не очень понятна. Главный вопрос: так собирались немцы отходить от Ленинграда или нет? Это к вопросу о снятии Блокады. Если нет, то как им удалось вырваться из Красносельского (кажется так) котла. Если да, то почему был реализован план "Нева-2" (прорыв глубокой обороны)? Но это к слову. По теме меня более всего интересует, какое конкретное событие произошло 27 января? Начало второго этапа операции - 20 января, окончание - 30.

Answer (score 2):

Вот текст из Вики :

> «Янва́рский гром», Красносе́льско-Ро́пшинская опера́ция, или Опера́ция «Нева́-2» (14 — 30 января 1944 года) — наступательная операция войск Ленинградского фронта в рамках стратегической Ленинградско-Новгородской операции против 18-й немецкой армии, осаждавшей Ленинград.
>
> В результате операции войска Ленинградского фронта уничтожили петергофско-стрельнинскую группировку противника, отбросили врага на расстояние 60 — 100 км от города, освободили Красное Село, Ропшу, Красногвардейск, Пушкин, Слуцк и, во взаимодействии с войсками Волховского фронта, **полностью освободили Ленинград от вражеской блокады.**

Вполне нормальное словосочетание! Зачем нам надо сужать языковые рамки стандартными наборами типа "глубокого удовлетворения" или "снятия блокады"?  Давайте заглянем в Нацкорпус :

> Вадим Кожевников. Щит и меч. Книга вторая (1968) ―Но ведь русские большевики остались теми же большевиками, которые первыми заключили с Германией Рапалльский договор и этим **освободили ее от блокады** держав―победительниц, ― напомнил Вайс.
> В. Я. Шишков. Емельян Пугачев. Книга вторая. Ч. 3 (1939-1945) Бибиков понимал, что Кунгур является важным пунктом, и старался скорее **освободить его от блокады**.
> Праздник в Ленинграде (**1945.01.30**) // «Советское искусство», 1945  День годовщины **освобождения Ленинграда от вражеской блокады** превратился в подлинный всенародный праздник.

Возражения против **освобождения от блокады** - надуманные и неосновательные.
Дополнение.
Газета "Ленинградская правда" от 28 января 1944 года :
[image: Газета]
Черным по белому : "**Ленинград полностью освобожден от вражеской блокады.**"
В то время всем ленинградцам было понятно, что это означает. Нынче некоторые граждане заявляют : "А я не понимаю! А это неправильно так говорить..."
Печальное непонимание, мягко выражаясь.
Рекомендую всем сомневающимся внимательно перечитать все ссылки, мною приведенные, начиная с 1709 года и заканчивая нынешним временем. Я лично доверяю чувству языка русских писателей, журналистов и других образованных людей : **от блокады можно и нужно освобождать**. В том числе от невежественной и неграмотной блокады.

> Ф. В. Булгарин. Воспоминания (1846-1849) Беннигсен хотел отрезать корпуса Нея и Бернадота, разбить каждый отдельно и потом **освободить от блокады Данциг, Грауденец и Кольберг.**
>
> А. А. Щербинин. Военный журнал 1813 года (1813) Марш, которого Жомини называет бессмертным, доставивший ему возможность **освободить от блокады все крепости** Силезии, между тем как Даун воображал, что Фридрих пойдет в Дрезден.

Comment: Из дневника ленинградской девочки Галины Зимницкой :  
>27 января 

Могучий голос Левитана: «Сообщение Совинформбюро. **Полное освобождение Ленинграда от вражеской блокады!**». Вот оно, такое долгожданное и радостное известие. Вечером будет салют! **Нет, не могу писать, плачу от счастья**.

Comment: >Что ж вы такие зашоренные?! Все-то вам нельзя...  
  
Одного не пойму. Что ж Вы раз за разом что-то доказываете вечно зашоренным личностям, которые не желают понимать, что именно вы доказываете? Ну найдите специалистов, достойных Вас выслушать - и оценить... Так нет, надо с упрямством, достойным лучшего применение долбить тех, кто хорошо помнит цену Вашим аргументам.

Comment: Ну давай, опровергни мои аргументы))))))) Не надорвешься, бегемотус?!

Comment: >Ну давай, опровергни мои аргументы))))))) Не надорвешься, бегемотус?!  
  
Не вижу аргументов. Вижу истерику на пустом месте.

Comment: По крайней мере мне не приходится каждый раз вычищать следы своей деятельности.

Comment: Ты страдаешь манией величия и бережешь каждую буковку, которую настучал по клаве))) Мне абсолютно безразличны все разговорные архивы всех сетевых ресурсов.

Comment: "Нынче некоторые граждане заявляют..."
Уважаемый, спасибо за мнение и ... проходите дальше, не задерживайте. Я понял Вашу мысль, спасибо еще раз. 

По крайней мере неумно приводить цитату из СМИ в качестве доказательства правильности и чистоты сомнительного (ТОЛЬКО для меня) оборота речи. 

Спор принял неприемлемую для меня форму, поэтому всем большое спасибо за мнения.

Comment: И вам спасибо. Изучайте исторические источники, не пожалеете! К тому же я привел достаточно литературных цитат, если **заметили**. Остальные участники ограничились собственными рассуждениями, ничего и никому не доказывающими. Привет, пишите еще, коли возникнут сомнения **в чистоте**. И поспрошайте ветеранов, которые освобождали Ленинград от фашистской блокады, нет ли у них каких сомнений в правильности их действий...

Answer (score 2):

По мне *освобождение от блокады* вполне допустимое словосочетание. А вот что такое *полное освобождение от блокады* я не понимаю. Что это означает? То что ленинградцы после этого куда угодно могли отправиться? Так 27 января 1944, по некоторым направлениям, немцы уже в 60 км от города стояли. Значит получается, освобождение от блокады было далеко не полным.

Возражение против *снятия блокады* высосаны из пальца. Действительно осаду снимает осаждающий, а не осаждённый. Но ведь именно это и произошло! В результате действий советских войск, немцы вынуждены были отступить, и прекратить (полностью снять) блокаду Ленинграда.

Ещё не нравится использование в официальном названии коминтерновского понимания фашизма (сами немцы Третьего Рейха себя фашистами не считали), но это уже несущественные в этом вопросе , субъективные частности.

Comment: >Действительно осаду снимает осаждающий, а не осаждённый. Но ведь именно это и произошло!  
  
О том и речь. Представляете, кабы день Победы назывался "днем Поражения (немцев)".

Comment: @Дерзкий. Гитлеровская Германия никогда не считала себя фашистским государством и различия между фашистским режимом Муссоллини и нацистским режимом Гитлера велики. Начиная хотя бы с того, что высшей ценностью фашизма является государство, а не нация. Однако, название NSDAP (национал-**социалистическая** немецкая **рабочая** партия) не могло понравится коммунистам, и на Седьмом съезде Коминтерна в 1935 году фашизм, нацизм и ряд других антикоммунистических режимов объединили под словом фашизм. В советской историографии так и закрепилось. Хотя насколько такое объединение приемлемо вопрос спорный

Comment: @behemothus, 27 января - очень условная дата, насколько помню, железнодорожное сообщение было восстановлено раньше, операция по отбрасыванию немцев от Ленинграда не завершилась и кроме сообщения Совинформбюро и салюта в Ленинграде ничем особенным эта дата не выделяется. Так что если давать исторически точную формулировку, то **снятие** (не добровольное конечно) подходит лучше всего.

Comment: Заведите тему : Почему *фашистскую Германию* непозволительно называть **фашистской**.

Comment: >27 января - очень условная дата  
  
Да. О том и речь. Но ведь даже её как-то должны объяснять...  
Получается, что отмечаем дату салюта. Но после Курска вообще салютовать было принято по любому поводу и при первой возможности.  
  
>то снятие (не добровольное конечно) подходит лучше всего   
  
Для военных историков - возможно, хотя и это обсуждаемо. Но никак не не для названия праздника.  
Кстати, на войне "добровольной" бывает только капитуляция.

Comment: @Дерзкий, я не считаю вопрос о режиме в Третьем Рейхе относится к филологии. Это терминологические разборки историков, если вам это интересно можете задать вопрос, постараюсь ответить. Поэтому я в ответе и написал, что это мои субъективные придирки, которым в рамках обсуждаемого вопроса можно и пренебречь.

Из подобных разборок актуальных в наше время, могу ещё назвать вопрос о классификации события 25.10. (7.11.) 1917 года. Это была революция или переворот? Кстати, в "Едином учебники" эту проблему обошли очень забавно, объединив февраль с октябрём.

Comment: Переименовали праздник по просьбе самих ветеранов, дело тянулось долгие годы, чиновники возражали, но все же закон подписан.

Answer (score 1):

Мне тоже непривычно это слышать. Но если вдуматься, освободить-вернуть свободу, а блокада как раз несвобода, изоляция от страны.Может, в главном значении слова "освободить"(от бедствия, от изоляции) это и верно. Говорим же мы "освободить от сетей...", хотя их снимаем, вот и здесь в переносном смысле освободить=снять.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила.
Синоним, НМВ, "осада". Осаду снимают, от нее нельзя освободить. Буду думать дальше ))

Comment: Что ж вы такие зашоренные?! Все-то вам нельзя...
> Анастас Микоян. Так было (1971-1974)  И хотя **полное освобождение от осады Ленинграда** произошло годом позже, прорыв блокады в январе 1943 г. явился переломным моментом в исторической битве за город...

А. П. Ладинский. Последний путь Владимира Мономаха (1960)  Действительно, императорские войска **освободили крепость от осады**, Генрих обвенчался с маркграфиней и издал манифест, в котором предписывал молиться во всех церквах за новую императрицу, ― а ей тогда едва ли исполнилось двадцать лет.

Comment: >Осаду снимают, от нее нельзя освободить.   
  
Осада совсем не синоним блокады.
Под осадой понимают ситуацию, когда объект оказывается в зоне оперативной досягаемости противника.  
Осада сама по себе не предполагает разрыв коммуникаций осажденной стороны. 
Возможна блокада без осады (блокада Кубы, например) - и, естественно, наоборот.
В нашем случае ***осада*** Ленинграда продолжалась до августа 1944 г.